# C# system.process stdin/stdout handling with Unity3D

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine, process

I asked a very similar question one week ago and I still try to find an answer.

I setup a complete new Unity3D project, put an object in it, create a C# script and put the following code in the Start() method.

```
void Start() {

    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "gnome-terminal";
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; for testing
    myProcess.Start();
    //Thread.Sleep(6000); somebody suggest wait some time, but it make no difference
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("sensible-browser");

}
```

I build the project for my Linux Ubuntu system and execute it. A new terminal appears and that's it. Normally, now the browser should be open but it doesn't.

That's only my test program. In my origin one I have to read/write from/into the stdin/stdout.

I'm fully desperate and hopefully anyone of you can help me

Thanks

Comment: did you try to close the streamwriter at the end? `myProcess.StandardInput.Close();`

Comment: Yes, in this case the terminal is still open but nothing happen.

Comment: if it doesn't even write "sensible-browser", try calling the last line with a delay.

Comment: I used the Tread.Sleep(6000) but after that, it doesn't execute or show anything. I also try something like "echo Test" or "echo Test > Test.txt" but I don't get any output and it does not write into the file.

Comment: `RedirectStandardOutput` is `true`. So all ouput of the process is redirected to `myProcess.StandardInput`. Thus the terminal won't output anything or redirect anything to `Test.txt`.

Comment: Have you attached the script to a GameObject in the scene? I don't know if the app built by Unity3D for linux will be started from a terminal or not. You may incorrectly taken that terminal as your process.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bash` instead of `gnome-terminal`.

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "bash";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("sensible-browser");
myProcess.StandardInput.Close();
```

Comment: I copy your code but when I execute it nothing happens, even the terminal didn't open yet. I get the same result when I try it with the full PATH : myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";

Comment: Your code doesn't work on **mono** but mine works (tested on Ubuntu 14.04). I don't have Unity3D for linux installed so I cannot test the code for you with the mono that Unity3D uses.

Comment: I develop the project on my windows system and build it for the "Linux x86" platform. I try to execute it on a 14.04.3 Ubuntu machine, and my main program runs without any errors. About your second question: Yes, I create a new project and attached the script to a simple cube in the scene (only for testing)

Comment: I suggest you install Unity3D for linux and debug in MonoDevelop to find out what happens exactly. And If your app mainly runs on linux, it's better to develop it on linux. Problems is always coming and debugging is better than trying and guessing.

Comment: [**mono** and **mcs**](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/) that Unity3D uses should be somewhere in its installation directory. You may try that first.